# Is there a way to access a Google Sheet's version history using python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I use gspread but if another library does it, I can use it as well

I couldn't find a way in my research

Comment: You may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71083118/iterate-through-all-previous-versions-of-google-sheets and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742318/how-to-get-previous-versions-of-a-spreadsheet-with-google-docs-api

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's API Client Libraries by using this command `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`, `pip install --upgrade google-auth-httplib2`, and `pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib` or by following the very first steps in this quick start at [Drive API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python).

The following methods will be used:

- ***Revisions.list*** **method**, documentation at [Revision.list reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) to list all available revisions of a file.
- ***Revisions.get*** **method**, documentation at [Revisions.get reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get) to get information about specific revisions, or download a revision for a binary file.

As mentioned in this documentation [Download and publish file revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-revisions) you can download revisions very easily. For our goal there are 2 distinct types of files in Google Drive:

- Binary files, using the Google Drive API v3 you can use the ***Revisions.get*** **method** with the `alt` parameter set to `media` you will download that particular revision, obtain the list of available revisions using the ***Revisions.list*** **method**, this only works with binary files, unlike Docs Editors files that acquire new revisions when edited by the user automatically, binary files will have revisions if newer versions are synced using Google Drive for Desktop (formerly known as Drive FileStream).
- Docs Editors files, with these the process is slightly different. When you use the ***Revisions.list*** **method** by default you will be provided with little information about the available revisions, using the `fields` parameter you can request `exportLinks` for the available revisions.

In python, taking the quick start code sample as base and after replacing the code sample with

```
    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials = credentials)
        results = service.revisions().list(
            fileId='The file ID',
            fields='revisions(id,exportLinks)'
        ).execute()

        revisions = results.get('revisions', [])

        for revision in revisions:
            print(revision)

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

This is a sample on how an API response in plain JSON looks like for a Docs Editors file. Depending on the file you are interested in getting you will need to use the respective link.

```
{
  "kind": "drive#revisionList",
  "revisions": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "exportLinks": {
        "application/rtf": "SOME_URL",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text": "SOME_URL",
        "text/html": "SOME_URL",
        "application/pdf": "SOME_URL",
        "application/epub+zip": "SOME_URL",
        "application/zip": "SOME_URL",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document": "SOME_URL",
        "text/plain": "SOME_URL",
      }
    },
    { <-> },
    { <-> },
    { <-> }
  ]
}
```

Keep in mind that for binary files you will need to list available revisions first and then once obtained the revision id use the ***Revisions.get*** **method**.